# Laravel problem with my app. question and based on the answer there needs to be a next question. questions and answers stored in DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, phpmyadmin

I am entirely new to Laravel and databases. I am making a web application for people having a problem with certain products. So I ask the user a question, and based on the answer the user clicks on, there has to be the next question. So I have the questions and the solution stored in the DB. with questions having an ID and a description which is the question itself. And the answers have ID, Question ID, Next question ID, and the description. The problem is that I don't know how to connect the IDs and make sure it goes to the next question based on the answer. Can somebody help, please?

**Controller**

```
use App\Models\question;
use App\Models\answer;

class QuestionController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $questions = question::all();
        $answers= answer::all();

        return view('question', [
            'questions' => $questions,
            'answers' => $answers,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my view, I already made the first question with the answers as a button, but I don't know how to connect the IDs and make sure the next question shows based on the user's response. I have everything set up and tried to make an overview for myself, but I can't figure out how to do it. As I mentioned, I am very new to this, so it's a little hard for me. I am using PHP, Laravel, and SQL. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: How many questions are you showing at a time? if you are only showing one question you can use `show(Question questionObj)` get the answers of one question and redirect to the next question url on answer selection

Comment: @Cerlin im showing one question at a time, but there are so many questions and answers i need to put in. So i don't know how to show a specific question after the question has been answered in a easier way. i just want it to automatically move to the question that matches the answer until the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options on how to do this, so in a certain way, there is no right or wrong. But I will present you one DB-structure to achieve this.

Please take my setup with a grain of salt, it's not perfect but I'll try to explain as much as possible:

#### Questions table columns:

- id
- content

This will list all questions

#### Question_instances table columns:

- id
- question_id >> foreign key to `questions.id`

This will list all question instances, which is just a wrapper around an existing question. The reason for this table's existence, is purely for re-usability of question-answer pairs.

#### Answers table columns:

- id
- content

This will list all answers

#### Question_answers table columns:

- id
- answer_id >> foreign key to `answers.id`
- question_instance_id  >> foreign key to `question_instances.id`
- follow_up_question_instance_id(nullable)  >> foreign key to `question_instances.id`

This will link question_instances and answers together. You can optionally provide a follow up question id to link to the next question.

#### Setup:

- There should be a unique constraint between `Question_answers.question_instance_id` and `Question_answers.answer_id` so you cannot add the same answer to the same question.

#### So lets try to assemble an Q-A example of how flow could look like:

- 1 (Q) What product do you have an issue with?
- 1.1 (A) Phone goto 2.1
- 1.2 (A) Watch goto 2.2
- 2.1 (Q) What version do you have?
- 2.1.1 (A) V3 goto 3.1
- 2.1.2 (A) V4 goto 3.2
- 2.2 (Q) What version do you have?
- 2.2.1 (A) V5 goto 3.3
- 2.2.2 (A) V6 goto 3.4
- 3.1 (Q) Did you try to perform the last update?
- 3.1.1 (A) Yes
- 3.1.2 (A) No
- 3.2 (Q) Is device connected to charger?
- 3.2.1 (A) Yes
- 3.2.2 (A) No
- 3.3 (Q) Did you dissolve it in acid?
- 3.3.1 (A) Yes
- 3.3.2 (A) Maybe
- 3.3.3 (A) Heck yeah
- 3.4 (Q) Have you tried throwing it into the grand canyon?
- 3.4.1 (A) Only with the glass side up
- 3.4.2 (A) Maybe

### How does this look like in the database with our current design:

#### Questions table:

- id: `1` content: `What product do you have an issue with?`
- id: `2` content: `What version do you have?`
- id: `3` content: `Did you try to perform the last update?`
- id: `4` content: `Is device connected to charger?`
- id: `5` content: `Did you dissolve it in acid?`
- id: `6` content: `Have you tried throwing it into the grand canyon?`

#### Answers table:

- id: `1` content: `Phone`
- id: `2` content: `Watch`
- id: `3` content: `V3`
- id: `4` content: `V4`
- id: `5` content: `V5`
- id: `6` content: `V6`
- id: `7` content: `Yes`
- id: `8` content: `No`
- id: `9` content: `Maybe`
- id: `10` content: `Heck yeah`
- id: `11` content: `Only with the glass side up`

So now we got all the content that the user is going to see. Lets connect the pieces together to create the flow we described:

#### Question_instances table:

- id: `1` question_id: `1`
- id: `2` question_id: `2`
- id: `3` question_id: `2`
- id: `4` question_id: `3`
- id: `5` question_id: `4`
- id: `6` question_id: `5`
- id: `7` question_id: `6`

As you might be able to see, the whole reason for this table to exist, is to make sure you can reuse a question, without confusing it's instance. Question_id 2 is being used twice.

#### Question_answers table:

- id: `1` question_instance_id: `1` answer_id: `1` follow_up_question_instance_id: `2`
- id: `2` question_instance_id: `1` answer_id: `2` follow_up_question_instance_id: `3`
- id: `3` question_instance_id: `2` answer_id: `3` follow_up_question_instance_id: `4`
- id: `4` question_instance_id: `2` answer_id: `4` follow_up_question_instance_id: `5`
- id: `5` question_instance_id: `3` answer_id: `5` follow_up_question_instance_id: `6`
- id: `6` question_instance_id: `3` answer_id: `6` follow_up_question_instance_id: `7`
- id: `7` question_instance_id: `4` answer_id: `7` follow_up_question_instance_id: `null`
- id: `8` question_instance_id: `4` answer_id: `8` follow_up_question_instance_id: `null`
- id: `9` question_instance_id: `5` answer_id: `7` follow_up_question_instance_id: `null`
- id: `10` question_instance_id: `5` answer_id: `8` follow_up_question_instance_id: `null`
- id: `11` question_instance_id: `6` answer_id: `7` follow_up_question_instance_id: `null`
- id: `12` question_instance_id: `6` answer_id: `9` follow_up_question_instance_id: `null`
- id: `13` question_instance_id: `6` answer_id: `10` follow_up_question_instance_id: `null`
- id: `14` question_instance_id: `7` answer_id: `11` follow_up_question_instance_id: `null`
- id: `15` question_instance_id: `7` answer_id: `9` follow_up_question_instance_id: `null`

The only reason to use `question_instance_id` and not `question_id` directly, is so you can define different answers to the same question, depending on your scenario.(see how question_instances.id 2 and 3 are the same question)

Every time a user selects an answer, you can select it's follow up question. Just be aware that you could make infinite loops this way ;).

If you have any questions, please let me know. I know it is a big example and I might not be clear enough at some points.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. Its a little much to understand it completely straight away for me, but its really helpfull! I really appreciate you for sharing this i will definitely try this! But i don't really know how to eventually work this out in laravel and make it fully work. I don't know if that is going to be a issue later on or not, im not very experienced. Ill find out later on. Thanks for you help tho!!

Comment: Np, I know it's a lot, even when trying to keep it simple haha. I would recommend using a command like `php artisan make:model Question --migration` This will create a model and migration for you. I would definitly recommend looking into https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch for a bit of an overview of features that you need to know.

Comment: just recently started with laravel. I got more into the basics of laravel. Into MVC and just how everything works and what it does, so yeah i know how to make models and controllers and stuff, but i havent yet learned about migrations. I kind of prepared myself for the web application im trying to make, but since i just started learning laravel and databases its pretty hard for me to make such thing so yeah. Im glad you helped me a bit, so i can move a little forward and try to reach my goal!.

Comment: are migrations necessary in this project? or can i go without? its a little unclear for me.

Comment: To build your tables, migrations are greatly advised ;) Thats why I added the `php artisan make:model Question --migration` command. If you already have the models but want to add the migration only(from scratch) you could do `php artisan make:migration questions`

Comment: As a sidenote, If you already have your tables, you dont NEED migrations. It's just a good reference to have for the long run

Comment: Yeah, i already have tables, thats why i was wondering if thats still necessary. Thanks for your reply.